# How can I make the list wider in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI right now and I'm working on a tutorial.

But in SwiftUI List, the part of name is cut like the picture. Do you have a modifier?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(modelData) {
            Device in HStack {
                Image(systemName: Device.image)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("\(Device.name)")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    VStack {
                    Text("\(Device.price)")
                }
            }
            .font(.title)
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of limiting as you do

```
    Text("\(Device.name)")
    .frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
    .scaledToFit()
```

use just

```
    Text("\(Device.name)")
```

It will be automatically sized to fit